# Finding a string in file and replacing in it php

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm parsing a .csv that contains some dates with the format `Jan 10, 2015` which I want to convert to a normalized date `2015-01-10`.

I made a function that if you enter the non-normalized date `Jan 10, 2015`, outputs the normalized one:

```
function dateParser($dateVal)
{
    $dateArray = date_parse($dateVal);
    $parsedDate = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $dateArray["year"], $dateArray["month"], $dateArray["day"]);
    return $parsedDate;
}
```

Now, I want to do the following:

1. Read the .csv file
2. Find with regex the dates
3. Get the date, call to the `dateParser` function and replace it on the file
4. Save the file.

How can I archieve this?

The regex to find a date with the form `Jan 10, 2015` (or `Jan 3, 2015`) is `\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}`. And this is my code:

```
// Get the content of the .csv file
$str = file_get_contents($csvFilePath);

// Of course this can't be done "on the go" so it's not working
$str = preg_replace('/\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}/', dateParser($HERE_I_WANT_TO_PUT_THE_REGEX_MATCH), $str);

// Save the output on the file
file_put_contents($csvFilePath, $str);
```

How can I make this? The `preg_replace` doesn't allow me to find the regex and call the `dateParser` *on the go*.

**EDIT:** All the coments and the answer are about the data convertion. I dont need help with the data convertion as mine works great. My problem is to combine the regex match and the replacement on the file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Why not use date()? `Date("Y-m-d", strtotime($regexvalue));`

Comment: @CBroe How can I use that in my code? I dont get the point. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to convert your dates?

```
$date = date_create("Jan 10, 2015");
$formattedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');

echo $formattedDate; //Outputs 2015-01-10
```

This should accept all date formats and convert it to the correct format.

To replace all the dates within the file you could use the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) functions.

e.g.

```
$str = file_get_contents($csvFilePath);
$regex = '/\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}/';

//Search the file for dates that match the regex
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);

//Replace each value that matches the regex
foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
    $date = date_create($m);
    $formattedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');

    $str = str_replace($m, $formattedDate, $str);
}

file_put_contents($csvFilePath, $str);
```

Comment: That's not my real problem, my date convertion works too. As you can read on the post, I need to use regex first to search for the dates, then transform it (on the way I posted or in your way, I dont care) and then replace it on the file.

Comment: @Borja, edited my answer... let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the error `date_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` as `$matches` is `array(1) { [0]=> array(116) { [0]=> string(12) "May 22, 2015" [1]=> string(12) "Feb 27, 2015" [2] etcetc` (it seems that it has two arrays inside, right?

Comment: @Borja, Are you doing `date_create($m)` or `date_create($matches)` ? The `$m` variable should be a string.

Comment: I'm using `date_create($m)` as you stated. Here's the content of `$matches` http://pastebin.com/SShDU96M . As you can see is a multidimensional array, so the first iteration of the foreach (aka the fist value of `$m`) is an array that contains the strings iteself.

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated my answer, I think that should work... (`$matches[0] as $m`)

Comment: Hell yeah! Working now :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.